Is React Query more efficient compared to using hooks?
Is React Query more efficient compared to using useEffect and useState, given that these hooks are built-in and easy to use? If so, why choose React Query?
Why is React Query more efficient than hooks like useEffect and useState?

Define “efficient”. It exists for dev efficiency, like most libraries; it includes a lot of often-needed functionality.

The react-query library is basically a wrapper around the builtin React hooks, check e.g. the useBaseQuery function in react-query. It might be more efficient because it implements caching strategies or other complex features that you would otherwise need to implement yourself. In the end it really depends on your use case. I suggest you check the documentation for all features it provides to judge for yourself.
